# Why is this HTML hyperlink not working, and how could I go about fixing it?

Tags: html, hyperlink

On a website I'm developing, I'm trying to make a list of links. But they aren't *becoming* links, and I honestly can't figure why.

Piece of code:

`<h2>Afrika</h2>`

`<ul>`

`<li><a href="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" >Arabic</a></li>`

`<li><a href="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausa_language" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" >Hausa</a></li>`

`<li><a href="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swahili_language" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" >Swahili</a></li>`

`</ul>`

It isn't any of the code around it causing this, because I had moved the link away from the list (didn't work), then tried commenting out the rest of the code (to no avail).

Which is more confusing since another .html file I have has its links working just fine. So I have no idea how I messed it up, since it looks like it should work perfectly fine.

EDIT: I copied the hyperlink code from another file, and now it works—despite that I see no difference in the code strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks fine and it's working on my end, the possible reason might be the Javascript/CSS styles you have applied to the `a` element.

**CSS:**
Try inspecting through browser dev tools and check if there are any styles causing the `a` tag from working with its default behavior. such as checking if the element has `pointer-events: none`.

**Javascript:**
Check if you have applied `event.preventDefault()` onClick event of the element `a`.

Comment: My css and js aren't in separate files, and I had commented them out too. So I'm not sure if this would work, but I'll still give it a shot.